# Tree data doesn't compile in haskell

Tags: haskell

```
data Node = Blue | Green | Red
data Tree = Leaf Node | Node [Tree]

main = do
  let a = Blue[Leaf Red]
  print 1
```

It gives me the following error:

```
main.hs:5:15: error:
• Couldn't match expected type ‘[Tree] -> t’
              with actual type ‘Node’
• The function ‘Blue’ is applied to one argument,
  but its type ‘Node’ has none
  In the expression: Blue [Leaf Red]
  In an equation for ‘a’: a = Blue [Leaf Red]
• Relevant bindings include a :: t (bound at main.hs:5:11)
```

And I don't understand why it says it got Node instead of [Tree]

Comment: Note that the `Node` in the first data declaration is _completely unrelated_ to the `Node` in the second declaration. The first is in the type namespace, the second is in the value namespace.

Comment: How can I make it work ?

Comment: You're going to have to explain what you are trying to do, because `Blue[Leaf Red]` suggests you're confusing Haskell syntax with something else.  Objective C, maybe?

Comment: You forgot the constructor for the non-leaf `Tree`.

Comment: As a bit of nuance to Alec's claim: the second data declaration has *two* occurrences of `Node`, and one of them is related while the other isn't. (Specifically, in `Leaf Node`, this `Node` does indeed refer to the previous data declaration.)

Comment: Try not to reuse names for type and data constructors until you are more comfortable with the difference. `data Color = Blue | Green | Red` and `data Tree = Leaf Color | Node [Tree]`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can create a `Tree` as a single leaf with one of the colors, e.g. `Leaf Red` or as a node with a list of other trees, e.g. `Node [Leaf Red]`. Your `main` function should look like this:

```
main = do
  let a = Node [Leaf Red]
  print 1
```

Or:

```
main = do
  let a = Node [Leaf Blue, Leaf Red]
  print 1
```

In case you also want to add colors to your nodes, you can redefine your `Tree` datatype to:

```
data Tree = Leaf Node | Node Node [Tree]
...
let a = Node Blue [Leaf Red]
```

Reading this may be confusing, so you should consider renaming either the `Node` type or the `Node` data constructor.